# read_sql_query Invalid object name on all tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to run a very basic SQL query through pandas' read_sql_query in Jupyter, i.e.

```
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name',conn)
print(df)
```

The query doesn't execute showing ProgrammingError 42S02 - Invalid object name 'table_name'. And yet, when I run the same query and replace table_name with sys.tables,

```
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM sys.tables',conn)
print(df)
```

the list shows all the tables including the table_name table. I also tried db_name.table_name and it tells me that db_name.table_name is invalid object.

What might be the issue?

Comment: did you specify the schema? e.g `etl.table_name` ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Datanovice pointed out in the comments, the database schema was missing in the query. After I added the schema abbreviation, everything worked